# Multiply columns in CSV with jquery-csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I have some CSV that goes like `UNIX timestamp, price (USD), amount traded (bitcoin)`. However, I also need the amount traded to be in USD, therefore I must multiply the 3rd column with the 2nd. Does anybody know how to do that?

Currently I'm using [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv):

```js
var originalCsv = `1366383202,748.680000000000,1.000000000000
1366471506,777.440000000000,2.700000000000
1368121200,685.740000000000,2.187400000000
1375783458,619.500000000000,1.000000000000`

// Parse multi-line CSV string into a 2D array
// https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv

var newCsvTemp = $.csv.toArrays(originalCsv);

// jquery-csv's arrays are made up of strings, but we need them to be numbers

// Trim whitespace and then convert to Number

var newCsv = newCsvTemp.map(row => row.map(el => Number(el.trim())));

// Multiply amount traded with price

// var newCsvMultiplied = newCsv.map();

$(".new").text($.csv.fromObjects(newCsv));
$(".original").text(originalCsv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/master/src/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
<h1>New CSV</h1>
<pre class="new"></pre>
<h1>Original CSV</h1>
<pre class="original"></pre>
```

Comment: You're basically asking how to access the elements of an array...

Comment: `var newCsvMultiplied = newCsv.map(row => [row[0], row[1], row[1] * row[2]]);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that surely did the trick :)